# XSSFColor.getRgb() returns null when there is a color

Tags: java, xlsx

I'm reading an xslx workbook using poi.apache and I want to get the rgb color code for the cells. When I try to get the rgb code form a XSSFColor, it returns null even though I know there is a color there.

```
for(int k = 0; k < r.getLastCellNum(); k++) {
    XSSFCellStyle ce = (XSSFCellStyle) r.getCell(k, Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK).getCellStyle();
    XSSFColor col = ce.getFillBackgroundXSSFColor();
    byte[] rgb = col.getARgb(); //null
}
```

Getting the inner CTColor object doesn't help either. It also returns null.

```
 byte[] ctRgb = col.getCTColor().getRgb(); // null
```

Has anyone else run into this problem and/or have a solution?

**Edit**

as Creakazoid pointed out, switching Background and Foreground fixed a lot of my problems. But now the issue I'm getting is with gradients of grey.

For example, a dark grey is returning as black(FF000000) and a light grey is returning as white(FFFFFFFF). Can I get the actual grey color code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why this is the way it is, but what you want is the fill *foreground*, not the fill *background*.

Replace:

```
XSSFColor col = ce.getFillBackgroundXSSFColor();
```

With:

```
XSSFColor col = ce.getFillForegroundXSSFColor();
```

I tested with Excel 2010 and this works as expected to report the "background" color. Though the wording may seem to indicate it reports the text color, that is actually controlled using the color property of *org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That did fix like 90% of my problems, which is great. The problem now is that I'm getting black(FF000000) when my color is "dark grey" and white(FFFFFFFF) when its light grey. Is there a way to get more specific color code?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem now is that I'm getting black(FF000000) when my color is "dark grey" and white(FFFFFFFF) when its light grey. Is there a way to get more specific color code?

I have found the workaround  :

```
XSSFColor color = ce.getFillForegroundXSSFColor();
byte[] rgb = color.getRgbWithTint();
if (rgb == null) {
     rgb = color.getRgb();
}
```